# NPM error (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception) in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-2015, npm, typescript2.0

I need to get started coding an Angular 2 application at my workplace but I get the following error in VS:

```
====Executing command 'npm install'====    

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudioTools.Project.ProcessOutput..ctor(Process process, Redirector redirector)
Error executing npm - unable to start the npm process
Error - Cannot load global packages.
```

I've followed Angular 2 VS 2015 QuickStart guide, located here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Prerequisites are all installed:

1. VS 2015 with Update 3
2. nodeJS v.6.9.1
3. TypeScript v.2.0.6.0

This error shows up in the output when I open the project or try to do a 'restore packages'
Thanks.

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as administrator?

Comment: Yes I am running as an admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the reason.. nodeJS was installed with the x86 installer on a x64 computer.  Installed nodeJS in 64 bit and it resolved my issue.

Hope this help anyone who has this error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need other version of Node. You have maybe too new version of Node I guess. According to this thread: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/476 
you should downgrade and configure VS:

> It looks like vs2015 does not work with the latest 5.0.0 Node. Replacing with 4.2.2 one solves this issue for me. To make Visual Stuido use the same Node and npm as cmd by changing some files including node.exe under following folder:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External

Look for this article also http://jameschambers.com/2015/09/upgrading-npm-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Not the exact same error on the link you shared but I gave it a try anyway.  I still have the same System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception exception..